# capture column name as value in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I just want to capture the subject name (column name) as value in new column where there is some improvements in the students marks after re-evaluation.

I have the dataset before re-evaluation:

| name | class | exam | maths | physics | chemistry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Grade - 10 | model 1 | 98 | 78 | 75 |
| Bob | Grade - 06 | mid term | 65 | 72 | 92 |
| Rose | Grade - 06 | model 2 | 91 | 70 | 54 |
| Michael | Grade - 07 | model 1 | 72 | 90 | 45 |

Now I have the dataset after re-evaluation, there are some improvements in some students marks, and there are new data on other students marks who took their exam recently,

| name | class | exam | maths | physics | chemistry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Grade - 10 | model 1 | 98 | 78 | **87** |
| Bob | Grade - 06 | mid term | 65 | **91** | 92 |
| Rose | Grade - 06 | model 2 | 91 | 70 | 54 |
| Michael | Grade - 07 | model 1 | **100** | 90 | 45 |
| Sam | Grade - 08 | mid term | 43 | 62 | 80 |
| James | Grade - 10 | model ` | 76 | 66 | 96 |
| Henry | Grade - 09 | model 1 | 34 | 91 | 70 |

Now, we need to concat these two datasets, and mark which row is updated, and which column got updated, so, the concatenated dataset looks like this,

| name | class | exam | maths | physics | chemistry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Grade - 10 | model 1 | 98 | 78 | 75 |
| Bob | Grade - 06 | mid term | 65 | 72 | 92 |
| Rose | Grade - 06 | model 2 | 91 | 70 | 54 |
| Michael | Grade - 07 | model 1 | 72 | 90 | 45 |
| John | Grade - 10 | model 1 | 98 | 78 | **87** |
| Bob | Grade - 06 | mid term | 65 | **91** | 92 |
| Rose | Grade - 06 | model 2 | 91 | 70 | 54 |
| Michael | Grade - 07 | model 1 | **100** | 90 | 45 |
| Sam | Grade - 08 | mid term | 43 | 62 | 80 |
| James | Grade - 10 | model ` | 76 | 66 | 96 |
| Henry | Grade - 09 | model 1 | 34 | 91 | 70 |

Now, the final output should look like this, with 2 new columns, I was able to eliminate the duplicates and added the new columns **any improvement**, but I got stuck on adding the other new column **improved subject**

| name | class | exam | maths | physics | chemistry | any improvement | improved subject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Grade - 10 | model 1 | 98 | 78 | **87** | Yes | chemistry |
| Bob | Grade - 06 | mid term | 65 | **91** | 92 | Yes | physics |
| Rose | Grade - 06 | model 2 | 91 | 70 | 54 | No | no improvement |
| Michael | Grade - 07 | model 1 | **100** | 90 | 45 | Yes | maths |
| Sam | Grade - 08 | mid term | 43 | 62 | 80 | New Entry | new entry |
| James | Grade - 10 | model ` | 76 | 66 | 96 | New Entry | new entry |
| Henry | Grade - 09 | model 1 | 34 | 91 | 70 | New Entry | new entry |

Below is the code, I used for this,

```
added primary key column by concatenating name, class, exam and secondary key column by concatenating maths,physics,chemistry.

dupedf = concatdf.loc[concatdf.duplicated(subset=['PrimaryKey', 'SecondaryKey'],keep=False)]

dupedf1 = concatdf.loc[concatdf.duplicated(subset=['PrimaryKey'],keep=False)]

for i,j in dupedf.iterrows():
    for k,l in dupedf1.iterrows():
        if l['PrimaryKey'] == j['PrimaryKey']:
            
            dupedf = dupedf.drop_duplicates(subset=['PrimaryKey','SecondaryKey'],keep='last')
            dupedf['any improvement'] = 'No'
            # dupedf['improved subject'] = ' '

        else:
            dupedf1 = dupedf1.drop_duplicates(subset=['SecondaryKey'],keep=False)
            
            dupedf1 = dupedf1.drop_duplicates(subset=['PrimaryKey'],keep='last')
            dupedf1['any improvement'] = 'Yes'
           # dupedf1['improved subject'] = 'column name'
```

in the above code, I am iterating only the rows which exists in both before & after re-evaluation datasets. iterating row by row to have fill the 2 new columns **any improvement & improved subject.** **I was able to achieve for any improvement column, but I need help with improved subject column.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution :

```
pkeys = ["name", "class", "exam"]

delta = df1.set_index(pkeys).sub(df2.set_index(pkeys)).lt(0)

mapper = { # this will handle multiple subjects improvements
    k: "/".join(delta.columns[delta.loc[k]]) # change the sep if needed
    for k in delta.index if any(delta.loc[k])
}

tmp = pd.concat([df1.set_index(pkeys), df2.set_index(pkeys)])

m = tmp.index.duplicated(keep=False)

tmp["any improvement"] = (
    pd.Index(tmp.index.isin(mapper))
    .map({True: "Yes", False: "No"}).where(m, "New Entry")
)

tmp["improved subject"] = (
    tmp.index.map(mapper).fillna("no improvement").where(m, "New Entry")
)

out = tmp.query("~index.duplicated(keep='last')").reset_index()
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   name      class     exam  maths  physics  chemistry any improvement improved subject
   John Grade - 10  model 1     98       78         87             Yes        chemistry
    Bob Grade - 06 mid term     65       91         92             Yes          physics
   Rose Grade - 06  model 2     91       70         54              No   no improvement
Michael Grade - 07  model 1    100       90         45             Yes            maths
    Sam Grade - 08 mid term     43       62         80       New Entry        New Entry
  James Grade - 10  model `     76       66         96       New Entry        New Entry
  Henry Grade - 09  model 1     34       91         70       New Entry        New Entry
```

With the [*Styler*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) to expose the improvements :

[image]

Comment: **NB**: `df1` represents the dataset before *re-evaluation* and `df2`, the dataset after *re-evaluation*.

Comment: getting error in this line ```df1.set_index(pkeys).sub(df2.set_index(pkeys)).lt(0)``` , ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'```. I guess you are doing the subtraction, if so, the marks values have some negative values as well, so each subject column holding a ```str``` values, not ```int```.

Comment: Of course the error is legit. I wonder why you did not precise that in your question! You need to give *meaningful* examples **that matches your actual dataset**.

Comment: That being said, before running my code, you can easily make sure that the subjects columns are cast to `float`.

Comment: it is working for this case. what if there is any other column with string values, or with date values. column like exam date, joining date, etc. and result column with pass, fail values.

Comment: Maybe just add them to `pkeys` like so : `pkeys = ["name", "class", "exam", "date", ...]` ?

Comment: How could we capture then if there are any changes in result column? From pass to fail or vice versa.Sometimes there may be some update/correction in students joining date as well.Is there any solution that works irrespective of column data type? By not adding everything to pkeys.

Comment: Your initial question talks about exposing improvement of notes (*numeric columns and not string one*). So, now with your comments (*all those details that you did not specified at first*), the question becomes a **moving target**. I suggest you to [open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new one in which you'll give an example that matches the format of your real dataset.